# CouchDB sorting by linked doc property

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I have the following data:

```
payment1: {
    id: "payment1",
    categoryId: "category1"
}

payment2: {
    id: "payment2",
    categoryId: "category2"
}

payment3: {
    id: "payment3",
    categoryId: "category2"
}

category1: {
    id: "category1",
    name: "Food"
}

category2: {
    id: "category2",
    name: "Leisure"
}
```

What I need is a view for sorting the payment data by category NAME. Is it possible in CouchDB?

Thanks in advance!
Ivan

Answer (score 1):

What is possible is a bit different from what you want.

Here is the map:

```
function (o) {
  if (o.categoryId) {
    emit(o.categoryId);
  } else {
    emit(o.id);
  }
}
```

You'll call it with `/mydb/_design/mydesign/_view/myview?include_docs=true` and get:

```
{"rows":[
   {"key":"category1", "doc":{"id":"payment1","categoryId":"category1"},
   {"key":"category1", "doc":{"id":"category1","name":"Food"},
   {"key":"category2", "doc":{"id":"payment2","categoryId":"category2"},
   {"key":"category2", "doc":{"id":"payment3","categoryId":"category2"},
   {"key":"category2", "doc":{"id":"category2","name":"Leisure"}
]}
```

In other words, payments are grouped by category, they are also joined with category's name. However, they are sorted according category ID but not category's name.

What you want would require two different sorts (i.e. "chained map reduce").

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could your provide an example for chained map reduce refering to category-payment-case? I'm new to CouchDB... :)

Comment: There is a possibility to link payments and categories not by categoryId but by category name and in the view simply emit category names as keys. However after changing a category name you have to update all the payments linked to this specific category. It's a little bit tricky but it works. :)

Comment: Chained map reduce exists in a CouchDB's fork called [CloudAnt](http://examples.cloudant.com/sales/_design/sales/index.html#basic) but not yet in the stable official version.

Comment: A very common way to solve your issue is to use names as references instead of IDs of external documents every time you can.

MapReduce way of doing things is to build an index from raw data. Data don't have to be normalized first. This is really a paradigm shift and have an influence even on user interfaces.

Comment: Thats why you often can't change your handle e.g. twitter several times :-)